# ASP.NET Web API OData GetNextPageLink method always return NULL if OData request contains $top

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

I'm trying to return PageResult for both types of paging (Server Driven Paging and Client Driven Paging). The idea is to set PageSize as value from $top if it passed in query. However, HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetNextPageLink method (essetially it calls GetNextPageHelper.GetNextPageLink method) everytime returns NULL if query includes $top. Is it possible to get NextPageLink if OData query includes $top?

I assume NextPageLink is part of the concept the Server Driven Paging and not intended for use in the Client Driven Paging model, correct me if I'm wrong. However, I can not find any mentions about my theory on MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/overview).

```cs
public static PageResult<T> GetPageResult<T>(IQueryable<T> query, ODataQueryOptions<T> queryOptions) where T: class
        {
            IQueryable filteredList = queryOptions.Top == null 
                ? queryOptions.ApplyTo(query, new ODataQuerySettings { PageSize = DefaultPageSize })
                : queryOptions.ApplyTo(query, new ODataQuerySettings { PageSize = queryOptions.Top.Value });

            var nextPageLink = queryOptions.Top == null 
                ? queryOptions.Request.GetNextPageLink(DefaultPageSize) 
                : queryOptions.Request.GetNextPageLink(queryOptions.Top.Value );

            var result = new PageResult<T>(
                filteredList as IEnumerable<T>,
                nextPageLink,
                queryOptions.Request.ODataProperties().TotalCount);

            return result;
        }
```

Assembly: Microsoft.AspNet.OData lib 7.5.0

Comment: This comment on the OData WebApi GitHub repo might help explain the behaviour https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2308#issuecomment-704408821

Comment: Thanks, @John Gathogo. That helps.